# Click & Drag: Move the Camera vs. the World

Tags: 2d, 3d, game-mechanics, input, user-experience

I've been tasked with finding out more information as it pertains to "Click & Drag" to change the users viewpoint in a scene, but I'm having troubles finding any definitive information.

NOTE: This is about user expectation/experience, not how to set up a view matrix or anything technical like that.

We have a scene that can be either 2D (overhead view) or 3D (1st-person POV), It's probably important to note that there is no avatar, per se, just a god-like view of the scene. I think a good metaphor would be viewing a board game or RTS.

If the user clicks and holds the left mouse button and drags the mouse, the view changes. Currently we have this implemented as though the user were dragging the camera around the scene. However, there is a lively debate going on as to whether we should be dragging the world around instead. To put it another way, if the user drags the mouse left, should the scene move to the left (with the mouse) or to the right (opposite the mouse).

I've seen both implementations in various games I've looked at.

I thought for sure there would some research on when is best to implement each way of doing things, but I'm not seeing anything related to UX best practices (only technical articles). Would anyone have more insight into this?

Comment: To measure how many of your users prefer it one way versus the other, the best way is to **ask your users**. Run a user study. Your users could very easily be a distinct population from the users of any previous app or study, so getting answers about *their* users won't necessarily tell you anything about what *your* users prefer.

Comment: This is a question about user experience. Maybe you can get a better answer in [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).